# Displaying Google Map API V3 in ASP.net Web Form

Tags: google-maps-api-3, webforms

I am trying to display Google Map in my ASP.net web form page.

The javascript is as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxxxx&sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var mapcv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');            

        map = new google.maps.Map(mapcv,
            mapOptions);

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

I used the following HTML and it doesn't work if I put the Div Tag within the form tag.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="map-canvas" ></div>
</form>
```

But if I move Div tag outside of the form tag as below, it works

```
<div id="map-canvas" ></div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">        
    </form>
```

I want to put the Div tag inside the form.  Could you please help me how I could do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the div width and height to see it! Your map is there but not visible :)

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
```

You could also set them in css in the header:

```
 <style>
    html, body, #form1, #map_canvas
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem if it is inside form tag. I have posted a example here.. Can you take a look http://deepumi.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/google-map-3-with-multiple-locations-in-asp-net-c/